# How to add each item 23 attribute

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know how to describe my question better. So here's an example:
I have two tabs in one spreadsheet: "A" and "B". Sheet A has a list of items, only one column but number of rows might change.

[image]

And then Sheet B has 23 rows of data. Well I didn't really wrote all 23 rows in this example.

[image]

And I want to combine A and B to have every item in A has 23 rows of attributes in B. Looks like this:

[image]

How can I do this using a macro since Sheet A can have 1k+ rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do exactly as you want:

```
Sub Angie()

    Dim i&, j&, k&, v, w, x

    With Sheets("a"): v = .[a1].Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row): End With
    With Sheets("b"): w = .[a1].Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row): End With

    ReDim x(1 To UBound(v) * UBound(w), 1 To 2)
    x(1, 1) = v(1, 1): x(1, 2) = w(1, 1)

    k = 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(v)
        For j = 2 To UBound(w)
            k = k + 1
            x(k, 1) = v(i, 1)
            x(k, 2) = w(j, 1)
        Next
    Next
    Sheets("a").[c1:d1].Resize(UBound(x)) = x

End Sub
```

Note: this will place the results in columns C and D of sheet "A". You can change where the output goes by editing within the square brackets on the last line.

Comment: Hi Excel Hero! It works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy without VBA. In a third sheet in A2 and copied down to suit:

```
   =OFFSET(A!A$2,INT((ROW()-1)/23),)
```

then copy  A2:A24 of `B` into B2:B24 of the third sheet and double click the fill-handle.

Comment: I don't think he wants to do it manually... every time a list changes in the amound of items, he needs to do the whole process it again. And for doing someting like that just 1 time, ppl wont come here asking for help... (i hope so) :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it - this time using ADO to create the output. This creates a Cartesian product or cross join in SQL. The effect of this is to produce every possible combination that uses one row from each sheet.

This will work if the workbook is saved as .xlsm file. If you are using the older .xls format then comment out the Excel 2007 onwards connection string and remove the comments around the Excel 97-2003 connection string

```
Option Explicit

Sub cartesian_product()

' Set up connection
Dim cn As Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

' Connection string for Excel 2007 onwards .xlsm files
With cn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

' Connection string for Excel 97-2003 .xls files
' It should also work with Excel 2007 onwards worksheets
' as long as they have less than 65536 rows
'With cn
'    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
'    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
'        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"";"
'    .Open
'End With

' Create and run the query
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Cartesian product
rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].[Item], [Sheet2$].[Attribute] FROM [Sheet1$], [Sheet2$];", cn

' Output the field names and the results
Dim fld As Object
Dim i As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

' Tidy up
rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

With VBA the solution would be something like:

```
Sub adding()
  Dim Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant
  Dim runner1 As Variant, runner2 As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Arr1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A25").Value
  Arr2 = Sheets(2).Range("A1:A25").Value
  i = 1
  For Each runner1 In Arr1
    For Each runner2 In Arr2
      Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = runner1
      Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = runner2
      i = i + 1
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

What it does:

- It loops all items in the first range

  - in each loop, it loops all items in the second range

    - in each loop it adds actual value of the first loop to the first column
    - it also adds the current value of the second loop to the second column
    - then it counts up `i` to inseet the next value in the next row

You still have to change the code to be as you want it.
Edit:
As it is written in the comments, this is not the *best* way to do it, but the easiest to unterstand (in my opinion). All the changes you may want/need to do:

- `Sheets(1)` is the sheet with the first item (you may change it to `Sheets("A")` or whatever you want/need
- `Sheets(2)` is the sheet with the second item (you may change it to Sheets("B")` or whatever you want/need
- `Sheets(3)` is the sheet where the long list will be printed out (you may change it to Sheets("C")` or whatever you want/need
- `i` is for the row to write in, having `i = 1` at the start to have the first row as *start* four your output (you may change it to `i = 2` to start at the second row, or change it to another number you want/need)
- `Range("A1:A25")` for `Arr1` and `Arr2` sets the ranges to get the data from (you may change them to `Range("A2:A24")` or whatever you want/need. they also don't need to be the same)
- the `x` in `Cells(i, x)` (`x` is 1 and 2 in the code) for `runner1` and `runner2` tells at which column the items of your lists will be printed (change it to a different number if you want/need to)
- having 3 or even more lists, you simply can add `Arr3`, `Arr4`, ... and `runner3`, `runner4`, ... to the code and then include `For Each runner3 In Arr3`, `For Each runner4 In Arr4`, ... (don't forget to have a `Next` for every `For` and an output for each `runner`)

**Edit:**
Just-for-fun-solution without VBA:
(I shortened the code for better understanding)

Cell `A2` in Sheet3:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/$C$1,0)+1)
```

This code repeats every item from `Sheet1` x times (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ..., while x is the value of `C1`.
The `-1` indicates the rows you are not using for output. Starting at the second row leaves 1 out (`-1`) while starting with row 15 would leave 14 out (`-14`)
The `+1` indicates the rows to skip at your source (having your source starting at the second row results in `+1`, starting at the 9th row would be `+8`)

Cell `B2` in Sheet3:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MOD(ROW()-2,$C$1)+2)
```

This code repeats the whole second list (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...) endlessly (just for the range you put that formula in)
The `-2` and `+2` are the same like in the first formula. However each is increased by 1 (or decreased for the negative part). Starting at the 4th row for the output is also `-4` for the negative part and having your source starting at the 6th row gives you `+6` for the positive one.

Cell `C1` in Sheet3:

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH({"",-1E+307},Sheet2!A:A,-1)),MATCH({"",-1E+307},Sheet2!A:A,-1)))-1
```

This code simply searches for the last cell in `Sheet2!A:A` which is not empty and gives you the row, but starting with the second row (row 1 is just a header) there is the -1 at the end to give the amound of items in your list. However, having filled cells below your list will count them also (including all empty cells between) so you may change it to `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50`. (When starting at the first item you need to delete the `-1` at the end.)
If you don't want to have an extra cell for this, you can simply replace `$C$1` with this code (without the `=`, also put it in braces `()` for the code in `A2` if there is the `-1` at the end or it won't work as wanted)
You also need to change the sheet names (`Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`) and cell ranges as you want/need it

Then simply auto-fill down till column A shows only "0" (column B will cycle endlessly)
Is very dynamic cus every change will be put in your output. (what also may be the downside of this) also for very long lists, it's better to use it with the extra cell `C1` (or what ever cell you want) and not include third code in the first two.

Have fun :)

Comment: It's not good to use For Each on arrays. Each element returned is a copy of the array's true element; it is not a ByRef variable. This has two consequences. Elements cannot be changed (not a problem here), but more importantly its really inefficient to make a copy of an entire array for no benefit. And to top it off, you are making a copy of Arr2 twenty-five times in this example . But you are advising Angie to use this and she has said that sheet A has 1000s of items. Using For Each here causes Arr1 to be completely copied one time and Arr2 to be completely copied 1000s of times.

Comment: was mainly for showing a short easy-to-understand-solution (for myself, i would only loop `Cell()` to fill an array and then paste it in one step (also much faster) like your solution (while i would use an easier scripting) :P